# Better more efficient bash script (grep)

Tags: bash, grep, performance

I have a script that I built ..  And it works fantastically -- BUT it's going to take an estimated 4 days to run!  I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Here's what the script does:

1. It gets all files from imageserver and loads them into **imageserver.txt**
2. It formats the file paths for grepping
3. Loops through **imageserver.txt** and greps `/var/www/html` per line
4. Writes to 2 formatted (exist and no) files for later usage
5. Write to log file for `tail` to track script progress

---

---

What I have is 2 files.

1. **imageserver.txt**  (about 250,000 lines)

   ```
   imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_tumblr.png
   imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_gaf.png
   imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_yelp.png
   imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_linkedin.png
   imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_twitter.png
   imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_angies.png
   imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_houzz.png
   ```
2. **search.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   echo "\n\n Started ...\n\n"

   # Clear Runtime Files
   > doesExist.txt
   > nonExists.txt
   > imgSearch.log

   echo "\n\n Building Image List ...\n\n"

   #write contents of imageserver to imageserver.txt
   find /var/www/imageserver/ -type f > imageserver.txt

   # Remove /var/www
   find ./imageserver.txt -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/\/var\/www\///g" {} \;
   echo "\n\n Finished Building Start Searching ...\n\n"

   linecount=$(wc -l < ./imageserver.txt)

   while IFS= read -r var
   do
   echo "$linecount\n\n"
   echo "\n ... Searching $var\n "

   results=$(grep -rl "$var" /var/www/html)
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "Image exists ...\n"
       echo "$var|||$results^^^" >> doesExist.txt
       echo "$linecount | YES | $var " >> imgSearch.log
   else
       echo "Image does not exist ... \n"
       echo $var >> nonExists.txt
       echo "$linecount | NO | $var " >> imgSearch.log
   fi

   linecount=$((linecount-1))
   done < ./imageserver.txt

   echo "\n\n -- FINISHED -- \n\n"
   ```

Basically I am checking to see if the images are used withing ANY of the html within the `/var/www/html` directory.

With that said .. Each iteration of `grep` takes about .5 - 1 second.  At my calculations that's 3 - 4 days..  While I SUPPOSE that's exceptable .. Is there a better (more efficient)  way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3):

The performance of the script is not your problem.

You are grepping **each** find under /var/www/html **250,000** times!

You'll want to replace that while loop with:

```
grep -rl -F -f ./imageserver.txt /var/www/html > grep_output
```

And then you'll parse that output file to get your statistics. Which will be tricky, but it won't take 4 days.

or, maybe as simple as

```
grep -Ff ./imageserver.txt -o grep_output | sort -u
```

to get the list of images used. You could use `comm` to compare this against the imageserver.txt to find the images *not* used.

Comment: I thought about this, and this would probably be helped by batching the search.  Using `grep -f` on huge amounts of patterns ofter makes the process run into memory issues.

Comment: Thanks @glenn --  I'll play around with this over the weekend .. It's a good mention also about the `-f` flag and memory .. I'll be sure to watch `top` and make sure all is well.